# Database Query to Wordpress Database Returns a Count, not Rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have the follow query I'm making to a MySQL database, for a Wordpress website:

```
global $wpdb; 

/*get time slots*/
$query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT routes.route_date, time_slots.name, time_slots.openings, time_slots.appointments
    FROM routes
    INNER JOIN time_slots ON routes.route_id = time_slots.route_id
    WHERE route_date
    BETWEEN 20140110
    AND 20140227 
    ORDER BY route_date, name
    "; 
$time_slots = $wpdb->query($query);
```

However the value of `$time_slots` is `245`. Just a number. I don't know why. When I make the query in phpmyadmin, using the exact query, I get the expected results.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get the array I'm expecting.

Comment: Please stop creating `[database-query]`.  It is entirely unnecessary.  We already have tags to cover the concept of database queries.  Your question already has those tags.

Comment: Didn't realize it was that big of a deal. Maybe you can send me a list of tags you've approved.

Comment: Duplicate tags *are* a big deal!  Tags are here to help categorize questions.  If people pick the "wrong" one of a set of tags that are effectively the same, they risk not having their question found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for all record

```
$time_slots = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

use for fetch row

```
$time_slots = $wpdb->get_var($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you are right

```
  <?php $result = $wpdb->query('query'); ?>
```

`$result` will contain the number of rows affected, not the results

do this instead:

```
          $result =  $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: `$wpdb` is the global variable to access the Wordpress database. It has nothing to do with the number of affected rows.

Answer (score -1):

function wpse_footer_db_queries(){
    echo ''.PHP_EOL;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse_footer_db_queries');